# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<CustomeProcedureName> to 'int'

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, types

Sorry for this simple question .

I have a Stored Procedure that return an int value , I'm trying to call this sp from my asp.net linq to sql project .

```
int currentRating = db.sproc_GetAverageByPageId(pageId);
```

But i get this error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<PsychoDataLayer.sproc_GetAverageByPageId> to 'int' .`
```

**Edit 1** 
The solution that friends implied didn't work . All the time it return 0 
For more information i put my stored procedure here :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sproc_GetAverageByPageId](
@PageId int )
as 
select (select sum(score) from votes where pageId = @PageId)/(select count(*) from votes where pageId=@PageId)
```

Comment: The actual result is wrapped inside an ISingleResult.

Comment: Whoa, three identical answers in the space of 1 min. Hope they work!

Comment: @cofiem - indeed. Hopefully, @Mostafa will enlighten us with the results :)

Comment: Thanks all for responses , But it return 0 all the time while it works fine in Stored procedure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should inspect [the `ReturnValue` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.ifunctionresult.returnvalue.aspx).

Perhaps the following works better?

```
int currentRating = (int)db.sproc_GetAverageByPageId(pageId).ReturnValue;
```

**Update:** since your stored proc returns a resultset instead of using a `return` statement the actual data will be available as an element in the enumerable returned by `db.sproc_GetAverageByPageId(pageId)`. If you inspect [the `ISingleResult<T>` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556.aspx), you'll see that it inherits `IEnumerable<T>` which indicates that you can enumerate the object to get to the data, each element being of type `T`.

Since the sproc does a `SELECT SUM(*) ...` we can count on the resultset to always contain one row. Thus, the following code will give you the first (and only) element in the collection:

```
var sumRow = db.sproc_GetAverageByPageId(pageId).Single();
```

Now, the type of `sumRow` will be `T` from the interface definition, which in your case is `PsychoDataLayer.sproc_GetAverageByPageId`. This type hopefully contains a property that contains the actual value you are after.

Perhaps you can share with us the layout of the `PsychoDataLayer.sproc_GetAverageByPageId` type?

Comment: But it return 0 all the time while it works fine in stored procedure

Comment: @Mostafa - how du you return the value in your sproc?

Comment: ALTER procedure [dbo].[sproc_GetAverageByPageId](
@PageId int )
as 
select (select sum(score) from votes where pageId = @PageId)/(select count(*) from votes where pageId=@PageId)

Comment: Thank you so much , You mentioned a very good point . I edit my stored procedure and I used return statement instead of select .

Answer (score 1):

This is actually returning an [ISingleResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556.aspx)

```
int currentRating = (int) db.sproc_GetAverageByPageId(pageId).ReturnValue;
```

Change your sp to :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sproc_GetAverageByPageId](
@PageId int )
as 
  return  (select sum(score) from votes where pageId = @PageId)/(select count(*) from votes where pageId=@PageId)
```

Comment: Ah ,Right now I realized you have answered me correctly already . I didn't see your post after edit . Sorry for not choosing your post as accepted answer . :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're actually after the [ReturnValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534556.aspx). You may need to cast it to `System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult` if it isn't already, then cast `ReturnValue`to int.

Answer (score 0):

one more thing you can do:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sproc_GetAverageByPageId](@PageId int ) as 
    select (select sum(score) from votes where pageId = @PageId)/(SELECT *  FROM votes where pageId=@PageId)
```

WRITE >>

```
"select * From"<< instead of "select Count(*)"
select (select sum(score) from votes where pageId = @PageId)/(SELECT * FROM votes where pageId=@PageId)
```

and after that:

`int currentRating = (int)db.sproc_GetAverageByPageId(pageId).count();`